# Get value of the selected item from dropdownlist using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```
`<div class="col1">

<strong>
<select name="Category" multiple size="4">

<option value="A">A
<option value="B" selected>B
<option value="C">C
<option value="D">D

</select></strong>

</div>`
```

I have div class containing a drop down list as given above, i just need the value of 'selected' item from the drop down list using Jsoup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for the `<select>` Element, iterate over it’s children and check if the `selected` attribute is present:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("your html")
String selectedVal = null;
Elements options = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "Category").get(0).children();
for (Element option : options) {
    if (option.hasAttr("selected")) {
        selectedVal = option.val();
    }
}
```

Or in short with a CSS-like selector:

```
String selectedVal = doc.select("select[name=Category] option[selected]").val();
```